# Remove text in a button tag using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, str-replace

I just want to remove text inside a button HTML tag.

When I call the function get_button, it returns a html code like this:

```
<button class="MyClass">"My Text"<i class="my icon"></i></button>
```

I just want to remove "My text" and the `<i>` tags, I tried using `str_replace` combined with `htmlspecialchars`, it doesn't work.

```
$button = get_button();
$button = str_replace("My Text","",htmlspecialchars($button));
```

if I `var_dump($button)`, I don't see "My text" but if I echo it, "My Text" appears, do you know why that is?

In a nutshell, I have this:

To be more specific the function returns this html code:

```
<button class="simplefavorite-button active">Retirer des favoris 
<i class="sf-icon-star-full"></i>
</button>
```

And I want to get this:

```
<button class="simplefavorite-button active"></button>
```

Comment: Where does `get_button()` come from, are you using a framework? If so which one?

Comment: the correct function name is this :

`$button =  get_favorites_button($fav);`

Comes from a Wordpress Plugin named "Favorites".

Comment: use strip_tags() for remove html tag and use str_replace for remove string

Answer (score 0):

I found out, a javascript function set the button text, it is not generated through php script...

Thanks again.

Sommy

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$button = htmlspecialchars(str_replace("My Text","",$button));
```

Instead of

```
$button = str_replace("My Text","",htmlspecialchars($button));
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: If i do so, then my `echo $button` shows html code as text which is not interpreted by my browser (this text doesn't not contain "My text"). 

In order to display it correctely, I do a `htmlspecialchars_decode`, then "My_Text" appears... I really do not understand what happens there...

Comment: There's no logical reason to think that this would help.